# How to unpublish php artisan laravel-module

Tags: php, laravel

Several days ago I installed nwidart.com/laravel-modules following setup documentation but then decided to delete it. Even I used this line but laravel still has the error about loading Nwidart provider

```
composer remove nwidart/laravel-modules
```

I tried to delete provider from `config/app.php` and also cleared cache but the error is still there
Any idea to delete and remove this module and unpublish this

Answer (score 1):

After I tried all solutions like cleaning cache, auto-dump and may other things, I just went to `config/app.php` and find this line and remove it completely:

```
'modules' => 
  array (
...
);
```

Now its working fine and everything works fine.